# Element style not allowed as child of element body in this context

Tags: javascript, html

When I check the W3C validator this is the only error I get:

Line 34, Column 15: Element div not allowed as child of element h1 in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
 
Contexts in which element div may be used:
Where flow content is expected.

Here is my full code: http://jsfiddle.net/xiiJaMiiE/azN8Z/

This is my code:

```
<h1>
  <div id=signin> 
  <input type="text" name="textbox1" value="Username" onfocus="<!-- if
  (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value=''; -->" size="19" height="10"/>
  <input type="password" name="password" value="Password" onfocus="if
  (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" size="19" height="10"/>
   </div>
```

Comment: make a jsfiddle.net example or a live demo

Comment: I have made it on jsfiddle @Godinall

Comment: Can't you just move the `h1` elements inside the `div` elements?

Comment: remove the div from the h1 then if it gives you an error!  Why are you even trying to put inputs into an h1 - it is a heading and should describe the content that comes after it

Answer (score 3):

The reason the validator throws an error is because div elements are not allowed inside h1 elements according to w3 specifications (and that is what the validator checks):

[h1 permitted content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/h1.html#h1-content-model): 
Phrasing content

[phrasing content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content):
Consists of phrasing elements intermixed with normal character data.

[7.3. Phrasing elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing):
a or em or strong or small or mark or abbr or dfn or i or b or s or u or code or var or samp or kbd or sup or sub or q or cite or span or bdo or bdi or br or wbr or ins or del or img or embed or object or iframe or map or area or script or noscript or ruby or video or audio or input or textarea or select or button or label or output or datalist or keygen or progress or command or canvas or time or meter

(notice there is no div)

Answer (score 2):

Your h1 tag is open, close it with a /h1 before starting your div and this error will disappear.

According to html spec, you can't place a div inside an h1 tag. you would be able to place a span and then use css display:block to get a similar effect.